# Magento Model gives different results when called from frontend or API

Tags: php, magento

I created a custom Magento's API call to retrieve the Quote Id associated to a user.

Here is the code that I use in my custom class:

```
public function quoteid($customerId){
  $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($customerId);
  return $quote->getEntityId();
}
```

Calling this function via the API always give me a NULL EntityId.

Here is the result I get:

```
Mage_Sales_Model_Quote Object
(
[_eventPrefix:protected] => sales_quote
[_eventObject:protected] => quote
[_customer:protected] => 
[_addresses:protected] => 
[_items:protected] => 
[_payments:protected] => 
[_errorInfoGroups:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[_preventSaving:protected] => 
[_resourceName:protected] => sales/quote
[_resource:protected] => 
[_resourceCollectionName:protected] => sales/quote_collection
[_cacheTag:protected] => 
[_dataSaveAllowed:protected] => 1
[_isObjectNew:protected] => 
[_data:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[_hasDataChanges:protected] => 
[_origData:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[_idFieldName:protected] => 
[_isDeleted:protected] => 
[_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
    (
    )

)
```

BUT, if I call the same lines of code from the frontend (I add these lines in index.php and loaded a page on my website) with a customerId I know, I get a result

```
Mage_Sales_Model_Quote Object
(
[_eventPrefix:protected] => sales_quote
[_eventObject:protected] => quote
[_customer:protected] => 
[_addresses:protected] => 
[_items:protected] => 
[_payments:protected] => 
[_errorInfoGroups:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[_preventSaving:protected] => 
[_resourceName:protected] => sales/quote
[_resource:protected] => 
[_resourceCollectionName:protected] => sales/quote_collection
[_cacheTag:protected] => 
[_dataSaveAllowed:protected] => 1
[_isObjectNew:protected] => 
[_data:protected] => Array
    (
        [entity_id] => 1234
        .... (ALL THE DATA HERE)
    )

[_hasDataChanges:protected] => 1
[_origData:protected] => 
[_idFieldName:protected] => 
[_isDeleted:protected] => 
[_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
    (
    )

)
```

My question is:
- Would you know why the same method called with the same parameters gives a different result, wether I call it from the frontend or from the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that it has to do with the fact that via the frontend, the store is fully loaded, whereas in the API call it is not. I would verify this by adding a `Mage::log()` call to your function to see which store is loaded:

```
Mage::log(Mage::app()->getStore());
```

The reason this would be an issue lies in the way `loadByCustomer()` behaves. Tracing the `loadByCustomer()` function, you see that it is simply wrapping the resource model's function of the same name. Looking at the resource model's function, we see it attempts to load the data from a custom select object returned by `_getLoadSelect()`, which leads us to the culprit. In `_getLoadSelect()`, it is checking if there are store IDs associated with the quote object using the `getSharedStoreIds()` function of the `sales/quote` model. If there aren't any shared stores, it won't return any quote data!

So, how do you ensure that the shared store IDs are present? Well, if the wrong store is being loaded by your API, you simply need to call `setStore()` on your quote object and pass in a valid store object before attempting to load the quote by customer ID.

That would probably look something like this (replace  with your store code or ID):

```
public function quoteid($customerId)
{
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore('<store_code>');
    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
        ->setStore($store)
        ->loadByCustomer($customerId);
    return $quote->getEntityId();
}
```

Source code referenced below:

**app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php**

```
/**
 * Loading quote data by customer
 *
 * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Quote
 */
public function loadByCustomer($customer)
{
    if ($customer instanceof Mage_Customer_Model_Customer) {
        $customerId = $customer->getId();
    }
    else {
        $customerId = (int) $customer;
    }
    $this->_getResource()->loadByCustomerId($this, $customerId); // HERE!
    $this->_afterLoad();
    return $this;
}

...

/**
 * Get all available store ids for quote
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getSharedStoreIds()
{
    $ids = $this->_getData('shared_store_ids');
    if (is_null($ids) || !is_array($ids)) {
        if ($website = $this->getWebsite()) {
            return $website->getStoreIds();
        }
        return $this->getStore()->getWebsite()->getStoreIds();
    }
    return $ids;
}
```

**app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote.php**

```
/**
 * Load only active quote
 *
 * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Quote $quote
 * @param int $quoteId
 * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote
 */
public function loadActive($quote, $quoteId)
{
    $adapter = $this->_getReadAdapter();
    $select  = $this->_getLoadSelect('entity_id', $quoteId, $quote) // HERE!
        ->where('is_active = ?', 1);

    $data    = $adapter->fetchRow($select);
    if ($data) {
        $quote->setData($data);
    }

    $this->_afterLoad($quote);

    return $this;
}

...

/**
 * Retrieve select object for load object data
 *
 * @param string $field
 * @param mixed $value
 * @param Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object
 * @return Varien_Db_Select
 */
protected function _getLoadSelect($field, $value, $object)
{
    $select   = parent::_getLoadSelect($field, $value, $object);
    $storeIds = $object->getSharedStoreIds(); // HERE!
    if ($storeIds) {
        $select->where('store_id IN (?)', $storeIds);
    } else {
        /**
         * For empty result
         */
        $select->where('store_id < ?', 0);
    }

    return $select;
}
```

Comment: You are totally right. When I call the API, the store code is 'admin', where as when I call the method from the frontend, the store code is default.

I added ->setStore in my API function and it now works like a charm.

As I want to make sure I am changing the store is that method only, I am calling a singleton instead of the Model (as I think that's what singleton are intended for...)

$quote = Mage::getSingleton('sales/quote')
                    ->setStore($store)
                    ->loadByCustomer($customerId);

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I really spent some time trying to figure this out myself. :)

Comment: Be careful with the `getSingleton()` call. I think you want to actually stick with `getModel()` here, because the way singleton works is it only ever creates one instance of the model. So, for example if you call `getSingleton('sales/quote')` from anywhere else in your code, even a different class and function, it will still return the same quote object! This could lead to unforeseen problems down the road.

Comment: Thanks for this feedback. And you are totally right with the misuse of getSingleton. I read further documentation and getModel is definitely what I need here.